# upload a file to the specific route doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Im trying to create a form to upload files, but when I upload a file, not appears in the specific route.   I gave permissions using chmod to the folder where files are uploaded. Help please.

JAVASCRIPT

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="subir">
            <input id="archivos" type="file" name="archivos[]" multiple="multiple" onchange="seleccionado();" />
        </div>
        <div id="cargados">

        </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        function seleccionado(){

             var archivos = document.getElementById("archivos");
             var archivo = archivos.files; 
             var data = new FormData();

             for(i=0; i<archivo.length; i++){
                 data.append('archivo'+i,archivo[i]);
             }

             $.ajax({
                 url:'subir.php', 
                 type:'POST', 
                 contentType:false, 
                 data:data, 
                 processData:false, 
                 cache:false 
             }).done(function(msg){
                  $("#cargados").append(msg); 
             });
        }
    </script>
```

PHP

```
<?php

  $ruta='/var/www/imgSube/';
  foreach ($_FILES as $key) {
    if($key['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ){
      $nombre = $key['name'];
      $temporal = $key['tmp_name']; 
      $tamano= ($key['size'] / 1000)."Kb"; 
      move_uploaded_file($temporal, $ruta . $nombre); 

      echo "
        <div id='subido'>
        <h12><strong>Nombre del archivo: $nombre</strong></h2><br />
        <h12><strong>Tamaño del archivo: $tamano</strong></h2><br />
        <hr>
        </div>
      ";
    }else{
      echo $key['error']; 
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: You are using ajax and formData...if you use chrome you can inspect the element and see if the file is passing in the network tab.

Comment: Try using a relative path instead of an absolute method.

Comment: You cannot upload files with AJAX. The standard workaround is to create a hidden iframe do a conventional form-based upload there.

Comment: @MarcB I tested the OP's code just now, and it works. It could very well be a path issue.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with FF 24.0

Your code works and checked out. I tested it on my own machine and the problem could be the way your path is setup.

Instead of using an absolute path as in `$ruta='/var/www/imgSube/';`

Try using a relative path, something to the affect of `$ruta='imgSube/';` while running the script from the root of your server, which is what I did.

If running your script from inside a sub-folder, then the path would look something like this:

```
$ruta='../../imgSube/';
```

Also make sure that your folder is indeed called `imgSube` and not `imgsube` with a lower-case `s`

On a Linux box, this will make a difference.

And for the record, I used `jquery-1.10.2.js` but I doubt that will make a difference.

**NOTE/edit:** This will not work with IE 7

Comment: -ii-I used a relative path now, but I don't get upload the file :(

Comment: @j_arab what permissions is your folder set to, is it `0777` or other? My folder is set to `0755` just to mention that.

Comment: @j_arab And your jQuery file is loaded? Which browser and version are you using, and are you doing this via a local machine, or WWW?

Comment: I'm using a local machine, and my browser is firefox 24.0. Jquery file is loaded, yes

Comment: @j_arab Try running it via WWW, am sure it will work. There's obviously a permissions problem and it's not related to your folder's permissions, but elsewhere. Are you logged in as `admin`?

Comment: Yes, I'm logged as admin.

Comment: @j_arab So, you're running your own webserver, PHP is properly installed/configured, right? Did you make any changes and didn't reboot/restarted Apache? And the folder name is correct, spelling etc.? No JS blocker? Firewall settings?

Comment: yes in www runs ok, but in local doesn't work... I used chmod -R 777 namefolder..

Comment: @j_arab I am not well-versed enough with local webservers to help out any further. I tried to help as much as I could with what I could think of.